# How can I make text fold around an element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text field that appends text to an `<li>` element and I would like the text that it appends to the li element to be arranged in a very specific way. I thought maybe add a small image and make that image invisible with css. Is there a more conventional way?

```
I want to be able to have text like this then(invisible element)
makes the text continue here(invisible element)
and here.
```

Comment: You mean like a `<br/>`

Comment: You definitely want a <br/> tag +1 Petah

Comment: Add as answer @Petah, you're spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you popping text into that element also add a css class to it

and define css class like

```
.icon{

background:url(my_desired_image.png) no-repeat size;
// other styles 
}
```

then whenever the element get text from field it will add class and class will show her image at the same time

like

```
I want to be able to have text like this then <i class="icon"></i>
makes the text continue here< i class="icon"></i>
and here.

<i class="icon"></i>
```

is your invisible element